# Getting daily averages with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime-format

I found a way to create daily averages of many variables, for example of a database that has the following structure:

```
Fecha,Time, DirViento, MagViento, Temperatura, Humedad, PreciAcu.
```

Each column is daily data every 15 minutes. I share the code, which, with the help of your comments I have adapted to my project. The code calculates the average of the columns Temperatura and Humedad as well as the sum of column PreciAcu. The code is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


data = pd.read_csv('tancoyol.csv')
index5=data.set_index(['Fecha','Hora'],inplace=True)

grouped = index5.groupby(level=0)
stat_cea = grouped.agg({'Temperatura':np.mean,'Humedad':np.mean,'PreciAcu':np.sum})
print 'Done............'
```

Now I have one more question, I need to convert to radians the DirViento column, how I can do this and how can add this new column to my data file?

In summary, I need to obtain 3 columns from the DirViento column agregate to datafile.

```
DirViento                       
1/07/2011 00:00:00        
1/07/2011 00:15:00        
1/07/2011 00:30:00       
1/07/2011 00:45:00      
2/07/2011 00:00:00           
2/07/2011 00:15:00     
2/07/2011 00:30:00     
2/07/2011 00:45:00         
.                            
.                          
.
```

Specifically:

First I need to convert the values of DirViento column to Radians (This should be a new column called Rad)
Second I need to get the sine of Rad column (This should be a new column called Sin)
Third I need to get the cosine of Rad column (This should be a new column called Cos).

How I can achieve this?