# Reshaping pandas DataFrame

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I have two DataFrame, each contening the same columns name and some same row names; for example one csv file with this content:

```
Location    method  reading  date
1             M      2.8    12-Jun
1             A       3     12-Jun
2             M      2.5    12-Jun
2             A      3.1    12-Jun
3             M      4      12-Jun
3             A      2.2    12-Jun
```

and anothe one with this content:

```
Location    method  reading  date
   1         M       2.9    13-Jun
   1         A        3     13-Jun
   2         M       2.6    13-Jun
   2         A       3.1    13-Jun
   3         M       3.9    13-Jun
   3         A       2.2    13-Jun
```

I would like to organize them into a DataFrame that look like this:

```
         1/M    1/A  2/M    2/A  3/M    3/A
12-Jun   2.8     3   2.5    3.1   4     2.2
13-Jun   2.9     3   2.6    3.1  3.9    2.2
```

where my dataframe columns name are each location+each method (example: 1/M is for location 1 and method M). How can this be done in a efficient way. I wrote something like this:

```
data1=pd.read_csv("csv1.csv")
data2=pd.read_csv("csv2.csv")
list1={}
list2={}


for index, row in  data1.iterrows():
  list=[]
  list.append(row["date"])
  list.append(row["reading"])
  list1[row["location"]+row["method"]]=list
```

but i am stuck there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let `df` be the first dataframe. I would use the pivot method as:

```
d = pd.pivot_table(df,index='date',columns=['Location','method'], values='reading')
```

which returns:

```
Location  1         2         3   
method    A    M    A    M    A  M
date                              
12-Jun    3  2.8  3.1  2.5  2.2  4
```

Then I'd combine the columns levels names to obtain a new list of columns:

```
L = []

for index,row in d.columns:
    c = str(index) + '/' + str(row)
    L.append(c)
```

and then assign the new `L` list as the columns of the dataframe:

```
d.columns = L
```

The result is:

```
        1/A  1/M  2/A  2/M  3/A  3/M
date                                
12-Jun    3  2.8  3.1  2.5  2.2    4
```

Hope that helps. The same works combining the two dataframes.

Edit:

If `df1` is the first dataframe and `df2` the second, you can combine them into one single `df` with:

```
df = df1.append(df2)
```

and then apply the method over it.

Comment: The pd.pivot() give me this error: pandas.core.groupby.DataError: No numeric types to aggregate

Comment: Actually I don't know, for me it works with pandas 0.16.2. I just read the dataframe through `df = pd.read_csv('df1.csv')` and do the rest.

Comment: it works now but when i try to loop now through it to add the "/", i received this error: ValueError: too many values to unpack because i have a lot of columns; how can i fix it?

Answer (score 1):

The function you're looking for is `pivot`. Make sure you read the tutorial here:

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reshaping.html

The fact that the data comes in two dataframes is irrelevant, so I concatenated them to begin with:

```
df = pd.concat([data1, data2], ignore_index=True)
df['loc_method'] = df['Location'].astype('str') + '/' + df['method']
df.pivot(index='date', columns='loc_method', values='reading')
```

Result:

```
loc_method  1/A  1/M  2/A  2/M  3/A  3/M
date                                    
12-Jun        3  2.8  3.1  2.5  2.2  4.0
13-Jun        3  2.9  3.1  2.6  2.2  3.9
```

Comment: it is giving me an error: pandas.core.groupby.DataError: No numeric types to aggregate

Comment: Try the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25397057/getting-average-of-pandas-with-groupby-getting-dataerror-no-numeric-types-to-a). The column 'reading' in your dataframe is probably not a numeric type.

Comment: you are right i went through some of my data and i found out that indeed there are some which are not numeric; when i try to cast it, it gives me this error: ValueError: could not convert string to float: OOR. How can i cast this in order to use the pibot function? Thank you

Comment: This looks like missing data ('out of range' perhaps?). You should try `df.loc[df['reading'] == 'OOR', 'reading'] = numpy.nan` before converting.

Comment: You can also handle it directly when you read the CSV file with something like `read_csv(..., na_values=['OOR'])`.